# ASP.NET MVC4 Routing - Multiple routes to the same location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, single-page-application

I am in the process of setting up a Single Page Application (SPA) and would like to setup, currently two routes.  For instance:

- Route 1:  `http://localhost` - this is the default route which requires authentication (Admin area)
- Route 2:  `http://localhost/<client>/<clients project name>/` - this does not require authentication (view only)

In the admin area, they setup the `<client>` and `<clients project name>`, therefore I know I need to setup this configuration in MVC4 Routes, but it is unclear to me how I would approach this.

Another caveat would be, if the `<clients project name>` was not entered into the URL, it would present a search page for that client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the great things about routing in MVC is the ability to route anything to anywhere, regardless of whether the url matches the naming of controllers and action methods.  The RouteConfig allows us to register specific routes to cater for this.  Let me show you how you can achieve this.

**Route 1:**

This is handled by the default route in the route config.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default", 
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                    action = "Index", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Hitting `http://localhost` will take you to the `Home` controller and the `Index` action method.

**Route 2:**

We can set up one route that will cater for `http://localhost/<client>` and `http://localhost/<client>/<clients project name>`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Client", 
    "{client}/{title}", 
    new { controller = "Home", 
          action = "Client", 
          title = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Hitting either `http://localhost/bacon` or `http://localhost/bacon/smokey` will take you to the `Home` controller and the `Client` action method.  Notice the `title` is an optional parameter this is how we can get both urls to work with the same route.

For this to work on the controller end our action method `Client` would need to look like this.

```
public ActionResult Client(string client, string title = null)
{
    if(title != null)
    {
       // Do something here.
    }
}
```

Comment: What a great explanation.  Thanks for this!  I am sure this will open me to more questions in the future.

Comment: Will this also work for Web API routes?  Where instead of using MapRoute you just use MapHttpRoute?

Comment: Yes this can also be used with MapHttpRoute

Comment: Ok, I have implemented this but now it is conflicting with my login management.  It calls /Account/Logoff, which is in the same format as the above.  Is there a way I can pass all Account requests off to it's specific area?

Comment: You just need to create a specific route for the Account controller. E.g. routes.MapRoute("Account", "Account/{action}", new { controller = "Account" });